# create a group variable in a data frame by a string variable starting from a certain value in R

Tags: r, string

I have following data frame.

```
sub1=c("2021","2121","M123","M143")
x1=c(10,5,6,7)
x2=c(11,12,34,56)
data=data.frame(sub1,x1,x2)
```

I need to get create a group variable for this data frame such that if the sub1 starts from number 2, then it will belongs to one group and if sub1 starts from letter M , it belongs to second group.

My desired output should be like this,

```
sub1 x1 x2 group
1 2021 10 11 1
2 2121  5 12 1
3 M123  6 34 2
4 M143  7 56 2
```

can anyone suggest any funstion that i use for this ? I tried **grep** funstion as follows, but i didnt get the desired result.

```
data$sub1[grep("^[2].*", data$sub1)]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
data$group <- ifelse(substr(data$sub1,1,1)==2,1,2)

data
  sub1 x1 x2 group
1 2021 10 11     1
2 2121  5 12     1
3 M123  6 34     2
4 M143  7 56     2
```

In case you do not know if it could be other cases than `2` or `M`:

```
ifelse(substr(data$sub1,1,1)==2,1,ifelse(substr(data$sub1,1,1)=='M',2,'Missing'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using substring and indexing to assign groups.

```
data$group <- (substr(data$sub1, 1, 1) == "M") + 1

data
#  sub1 x1 x2 group
#1 2021 10 11     1
#2 2121  5 12     1
#3 M123  6 34     2
#4 M143  7 56     2
```

---

Or extract first character using regex

```
sub("(.).*", "\\1", data$sub1)
#[1] "2" "2" "M" "M"
```

and then use the same method to assign groups

```
(sub("(.).*", "\\1", data$sub1) == "M") + 1
#[1] 1 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
as.integer(!grepl("^2", data$sub1)) + 1

[1] 1 1 2 2
```